# Maximum sum of digits from a given formula

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, problem-solving, word-problem

The sum of digits of the telephone number aaabbbb equals the two-digit number ab.
What is the sum $a+b?$

$(A) \space8$

$(B)\space 9 $

$(C) \space10 $

$(D)\space 11$

$(E) \space 12$

So far I have tried using the formula $3a + 4b = k$, where $k$ is made up of the digits $a, b.$
From my understanding, to get the maximum value of $a+b$. We would have to maximize the value of $k$. So by plugging in $9$ to be $a$ and $b$ we get $k = 63.$ Therefore $a + b = 9.$

I understand why this is wrong, as for some number $< 63$, there exists an $a + b $ where $a + b$ is greater than $9$. My doubt now is, how do I find this number.

Comment: However if you set $a=9$ and $b=9$ then $ab=99$, which is _not_ also the digit sum of $aaabbbb=9999999$.

Comment: Also, you're not asked to find the _maximum_ of $a+b$, just to find $a+b$ itself. There's only one choice of $a$ and $b$ that works at all. (At least if we exclude $a=b=0$ because $0$ is not a _two-digit_ number).

Answer (score 1):

Consider:
$$ 3a + 3b + b = 10a + b $$
implies that
$$ 10 | 3a + 3b $$
So you’re only in interested in those solutions for $a+b$ so that $3(a+b)$ is divisable by $10$. In your case this is only possible with option C. This does then imply that
$$ 3\cdot 10 = 30 = a0$$
so
$$ a = 3 $$
and thus
$$ b = 10 - 3 = 7 $$

If we did not know these possible solutions, consider: If $3(a+b)=X$, then $10\leq X< 3\cdot 20 = 60$ and $10|X$ and $3|X$. Thus $30|X$, so the only possible value for $X$ is $30$.

Comment: In fact $3a+3b+b=10a+b\implies 3b=7a$